# Intuition and technical explanation behind "3D-aware Feature Attention" in Sync Dreamer? (Multiview Generating Diffusion Model)

Tags: attention, diffusion-models, 3d-convolution

I am looking to understand the whole block on how the [Sync Dreamer paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2309.03453) has constructed the "3D aware feature attention" which is outlined on page 5.

> To
> enforce consistency among multiple generated views, it is
> desirable for the network to perceive the corresponding features
> in 3D space when generating the current image. To
> achieve this, we first construct a 3D volume with V 3 vertices
> and then project the vertices onto all the target views
> to obtain the features. The features from each target view
> are concatenated to form a spatial feature volume. Next,
> a 3D CNN is applied to the feature volume to capture and
> process spatial relationships. In order to denoise n-th target
> view, we construct a view frustum that is pixel-wise aligned
> with this view, whose features are obtained by interpolating
> the features from the spatial volume. Finally, on every intermediate
> feature map of the current view in the UNet, we
> apply a new depth-wise attention layer to extract features
> from the pixel-wise aligned view-frustum feature volume
> along the depth dimension.

I don't really understand much that's going on here and have many doubts:

1. What does it mean to project 3D vertices onto a set of target views? Can you get the 2D plane for a target view purely based on the azimuth angle and elevation? How do you restrict this 2D plane in size during projection?
2. What does it mean to have a view-frustum "aligned pixel-wise with the target view"?
3. What exactly is this depth-wise attention layer? I need some visualization intuition.